# What makes this passive voice sentence correct?

Tags: grammar, passive-voice

I've come across the following sentence in my English textbook:

• **It *was* said that we only *use* a small amount of our brain's capacity.**

As far as I know, we use "it is said" with present and "it was said" with past like this:

• **It *is* said that we only *use* a small amount of our brain's capacity.**

• **It *was* said that we only *used* a small amount of our brain's capacity.**

So what's with the textbook sentence? Is it something similar to what we do in reported speech with facts that are always true?

For example:

• **John: "The sun rises in the east."**

...which can be reported as:

• **He said that the sun rose in the east.**

or

• **He said that the sun rises in the east.**

I won't be able to reply for some time, but please shed some light on this while I'm gone. Thank you in advance!

Comment: Since the fact that we use a small amount of our brain's capacity may be regarded as an eternal truth, there is no need to backshift the verb. Instead the present tense "use" can be kept.

Comment: This has nothing to do with the passive: it would be the same if it started "they said". There are a lot of similar questions about tenses on this site if you search.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is, because the statement is (allegedly) always true.

*It was said* could mean 'someone said' (the speaker is recalling a statement made in a lecture or discussion) or 'people used to say' (but don't any longer). In this case, I think it's probably the first one.

Comment: Makes perfect sense. Thanks for clearing that up!

Answer (score 0):

John: "The sun rises in the east." or He said, "The sun rises in the east."

Indirect Speech: He **said** that the sun **rises** in the east. (NOT rose)

Active Voice: People say that we only use a small amount of our brain's capacity. (People say- simple present)

**It is said** (by people) **that we only use a small amount of our brain's capacity.** (It is said that- (simple present)

People said that we only use a small amount of our brain's capacity. (People said- simple past)

**It was said** (by people) **that we only use a small amount of our brain's capacity.** (It was said- simple past)

It was said that we only ***use***...(NOT '*used*') -It is eternal truth. So **backshift** is not necessary. The past form of the verb should not be used.

Comment: You didn't mention 'backshift' which is what this is all about.

Comment: BillJ, 
 Thank you for pointing it out.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed response! I appreciate it.

Comment: – 
Matt, You're welcome.